# From simple backbone to Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, handlebars.js

Our team made a lot of work to create our current large application. When we started to create it, we have not idea about Marionette.js
Now this library pretty much popular, so we consider the option of migrating our application from simple Backbone to Backbone Marionette to prevent outwork.
How do you think, is it possible for application with thousand lines of code? How much differences between those two libriaries? Maby you know guides about migration? Couldn't find it.
Thank you for all answers and sorry for my english.

Comment: This question is impossible to answer

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. And the biggest pros that it does not require migrate all at once - you can do it step by step.

The main idea of Marionette that this is just backbone with helpers.

First step will be replace your Backbone.Views to `Marionette.ItemView`. Your Backbone.Views will not be changed if you wrote your render code in `view.render` method.
You can extend your Views with Marionette features later.

Marionette is not not solid framework - you can use it partly and add more and more features when you will have time.

The easiest way to migrate is:

1. Just replace Backbone.View to Marionette.ItemView
2. Add Marionette.Application as entry point in your project
3. Add Marionette.Controllers
4. Add Regions and Layout management
5. Add Marionette.Module as your modules wrapper and started (If you are using `Require.js` as module loader skip this step)

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you for answer. I will try to learn this migrate direction deeper. Thank you again.